# want to insert uploaded csv file into database. it says 'no database selected' what did i miss?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

```
<?php
    //connection to database
    include("sql/connect2DB.php"); 

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
            echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
            echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
            readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
        }

        //Import uploaded file to Database

        $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $import="INSERT into user(username,password, user_type) values('$data[0]','$data[1]', '$data[2]')";
            mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
        }

        fclose($handle);

        print "Import done";

        //view upload form

    }
    else {
        print "Upload new csv by browsing to file and clicking on Upload<br />\n";
        print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='test.php' method='post'>";
        print "File name to import:<br />\n";
        print "<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";
        print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'></form>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Damn, yeah, what can produce the error "No database selected".. Let me think about it.. Hmm..

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: ... not mentioning that you forgot to include your connection code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for https://www.php.net/mysql_select_db

That should be run soon after the connection has been made

Though note the big red box on the page, You should look at upgrading to Mysqli or PDO.